# Manual Pagination on data from api call which returns Object

Tags: php, api, pagination, laravel

I'm new to Laravel and I'm working on a Test Project which will get some records doing an API call via curl. I was able to get an Object and I'm ready to process it on my controller like below:

```
$results = App::get_data($date);

$tasks = Paginator::make($results->data, count($results->data), 5);
```

I'm confused on how Manual pagination really works, I have 10 items on the $results->data and I already printed that out on my view including the links but the pagination is NOT working. Does manual Pagination work on this kind of setup, I dont interact on database, instead I'm pulling data from specific API call via curl.

Answer (score 0):

the Paginator class in Laravel was initially intended to be used with the Eloquent ORM such as:

```
User::all()->paginate($itemsPerPage);
```

To create a Paginator manually, you have used the right method, however, and it's not clearly documented, but the Paginator::make() does not automatically slice the array for you, you must do this manually as well. ie (assuming $results->data is an array).

```
$itemsPerPage = 6;
$currentPage = 2;

$slicedResults = array_slice($results->data, $itemsPerPage * $currentPage, $itemsPerPage);
Paginator::make($slicedResults, $totalItems, $itemsPerPage);
```

The above example would give you 6 items from the 3rd page.